How to implement follow/unfollow functionality without reloading the page in Django
I am building a web application using Django where users can follow or unfollow items (e.g., photos) from a list. Currently, I have implemented the follow/unfollow functionality, but it reloads the page every time the user clicks on follow or unfollow. I want to achieve this without reloading the page, so the user stays on the same page and the state changes (follow/unfollow) are reflected immediately.
models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='followers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Photo, Episode, UserProfile

def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    episodes = Episode.objects.filter(photo=photo)
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        is_following = photo in user_profile.follows.all()
    else:
        is_following = False

    context = {
        'photo': photo,
        'episodes': episodes,
        'is_following': is_following,
    }
    return render(request, 'photos/photo.html', context)

@login_required
def follow(request, pk):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_profile.follows.add(photo)
    return redirect('photo', pk=pk)

@login_required
def unfollow(request, pk):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_profile.follows.remove(photo)
    return redirect('photo', pk=pk)

html
        {% if is_following %}
            <div class="btn follow">
                <a href="{% url 'unfollowPhoto' photo.id %}">Unfollow</a>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="btn follow">
                <a href="{% url 'followPhoto' photo.id %}">Follow</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('photo/<int:pk>/', views.viewPhoto, name='photo'),
    path('photo/<int:pk>/follow/', views.follow, name='followPhoto'),
    path('photo/<int:pk>/unfollow/', views.unfollow, name='unfollowPhoto'),
]


Use an AJAX request.

Note that you also need to work with POST requests for follow/unfollow to make your server HTTP specs compliant.

are you allowed to use AJAX for handling these actions asynchronously?

need js post request + true or false response + js change html(if true)

I just want to use Django and JavaScript to solve this problem, is it possible?

It is. You can literally write your own Ajax wrapper using fetch -> https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
